# Where can I find dictionaries in multiple languages to do language detection?

Tags: nlp, dictionary

Since that Microsoft language-detect API is capped, and that Google's alternative is really expensive, I'm evaluating to create my own "api" to detect the language of a given text string.
Do you have any idea of where I can find dictionaries for many languages (at least 10) to begin?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries